# Evenly positioning of multiple images on bitmap

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm trying to position a number of images onto a single fixed size `Image`. The size of the fixed `Image` is 200 x 200 (pixels). Lets assume that the my `List<Image>` contains 3 images. The positioning of the first 2 images should be next to each other and positioned at the top of the fixed `Image`. The third `Image` should be rendered on the "second" line and centered underneath the first 2 images. This pattern need to repeat itself for any number of images in the list of images. Assuming the list contains 4 images, the first 2 are rendered next to each other on the first line, and the second 2 are rendered next to each other on the second line, and so on.
Here is what I have attempted so far, but the positioning is all over the place:

```
Bitmap finalIcon = new Bitmap(200, 200);
Image imgFinalIcon = (Image)finalIcon;
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgFinalIcon))
{
    int xOffSet = 0;
    int item = 1;
    foreach (Image icon in iconList)
    {
        int yOffset = 0;
        if (item > 2 && (iconList.Count() % 2 != 0))
        {
            yOffset = imgFinalIcon.Height / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            yOffset = (imgFinalIcon.Height / 2) / 2;
        }
        g.DrawImage(icon, xOffSet, yOffset);
        xOffSet += icon.Width;
        item++;
    }
 }
```

`iconList` is my list of images.
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you don't increase the y-Offset.

Try:

```
yOffset += icon.height;
```

after you displayed the 2 images on the top or when you displayed the centered image below.

And your yOffset is local and just exists in the loop, and it all time set to 0, when a new loop interation starts.  But it outside the loop.